# ¿Como dispara un evento de arrastre solo cuando se hace drop en un determinado div utilizando angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, eventos, drag-and-drop

y saludos cordiales. Estoy tratando de crear un app tipo drap and drop. Actualmente tengo dos componentes el que tiene lo que será arrastrado el div donde debe caer, ahora lo que realmente hace
es que al hacer drag de un elemento este pasa la data un array y un push.

El problema es que básicamente son con arrastrar el elemento ya se agregare, este evento los disparo
desde el componente que tiene los elementos y se renderiza en el otro pero quisiera conseguir el efecto
de que solo cuando esta sobre el div correcto este se dispara.

AHora no se si esto es posible ya que son dos componentes diferentes.

Basicamente tengo esto:

```
 dragStartHandler(ev: DragEvent, info?: any): void {

    console.log("data", ev);

    this.pages[0].businessContainer[0].businessControls.push(info);
    console.log('dashborad array', this.pages[0].businessContainer[0].businessControls);
  }
```

Ese es el emtogo que agrega al array.

este es el html donde se dispara

```
   <div class="col-5 mt-2 mb-3 ml-2 thing" *ngFor="let control of controles" draggable="true" (dragstart)="createDrap()" (dragend)="dragStartHandler($event, control, control.component)"  #dragItem >
      <div class="wrapper-item" class="drag-me" >
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center p-3 img-container">
          <div *ngIf="control.img">
            <img [src]="control.img |sanatizer">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center pb-1" *ngIf="control.texto">
          {{control.texto}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Esto es básicamente un componente

y donde solo es un div que va renderizado la data que pasa en otro componente. y no se si habra alguna forma de detectar donde es que se hace drop si poniendo un id o algo asi y con un if si no es tal zona
no dejar que se dispare el evento de agregado.

Comment: Hola que tal, lo pudiste resolver?

Comment: Si amigo pero al final solo necesite un observable.